Azure Static Web Apps Authentication Callback?
I'm using Azure Static Web Apps's built in custom authentication (aka Easy Auth).  I want to update a user table after authentication.  Is there any built-in event that is triggered post authentication that can be hooked into for this purpose?
I can only think of one workaround at the moment:

Redirect the user post auth with a post_login_redirect_uri parameter
to manually trap the event.
Then call the .auth/me endpoint from the client and then send that back to api endpoint to store in the DB.
Then redirect the userback to some other post login redirect (maybe stored in a cookie or something).

Obviously the above is suboptimal from a code base complexity (extra page & extra querystring params), user experience (extra redirect), and processing efficiency perspective (simply passing back to the server what is already there in the token store).
I recall that with OIDC auth there was a OnTokenReceived callback for ASP.Net Core.  Is something similar available for static web apps?

Yeah you can use the built-in functionality for managing authorization see the docs here under Manage Roles -> Function (preview) tab.
It lets you select an api endpoint by adding it in the config file as you'll see if those docs
{
  "auth": {
    "rolesSource": "/api/GetRoles",
    "identityProviders": {
      // ...
    }
  }
}

The api gets called after a successful authentication and the clientPrincipal object of the /.auth/me response object gets passed in. Your api needs to return whatever roles you want to give the user but you could do whatever else you needed to do with that user's info in the function as well. I used a managed Azure function and it works perfectly.
I found this blog post incredibly helpful for getting set up with custom authentication and authorization using Entra ID with Azure Security Groups for roles. https://johschmidt42.medium.com/role-based-access-control-with-app-roles-in-azure-static-web-apps-f6525d1b7d92
This was the content of my GetRoles function if it's useful:
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');

app.http('GetRoles', {
    methods: ['POST', 'GET'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        const user = await request.json();
        const roles = [];
        
        if (user.identityProvider == 'google') {
            roles.push('externalvendor');
        } 
        else if (user.identityProvider == 'aad') {
            for (const claim of Object.entries(user.claims)) {
                if (claim[1].typ == 'roles' || claim[1].typ == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role") {
                    roles.push(claim[1].val);
                }
            }
        }
        
        return {
            jsonBody: {"roles": roles},
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };
    }
})

